# How to drop all incoming network packets in CentOS except for one port and one source IP address?

Tags: firewall

I'm trying to drop all incoming network packets in CentOS except for one port (2323) and one source IP address (10.10.20.100)? Could someone help me do this from the command line in CentOS 8?

Comment: Do you have other rule with wich the new should live togheter? Or a policy?

Comment: https://shouts.dev/install-and-setup-ufw-firewall-on-centos-8-rhel-8#:~:text=%20Install%20and%20Setup%20UFW%20Firewall%20on%20CentOS,in%20UFW%20firewall.%20%20...%20%20More%20  This link goes into more detail but again remember don’t LOCK yourself out

Comment: Added more to answer but please read and understand ufw documents before you simply run commands from the internet.

Comment: You can do this with IPtables as well, if you drop all traffic, then add a rule on top that allows from the source ip and port that you want...

Comment: Thanks you all for your comments. This will be a local machine that does not see any traffic but some incoming packets from the specified IP address and port.

Answer (score 0):

Look into UFW “Uncomplicated firewall”

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
sudo ufw allow from 10.10.20.100 to any port 2323
sudo ufw allow ssh
```

You will have to setup ufw but it’s easy to do also have to change a few things in the config but again easy to use.

IMPORTANT make sure you don’t block yourself make sure you add a rule to allow ssh or someway to login

This link will help also

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-20-04

The commands and links I left will work but you will need to do some reading and make sure you know what rules you have before you enable the firewall.  There are also a couple commands needed to enable the firewall I did not included them on purpose so you don’t accidentally lock yourself out of your system.

As with everything on this site please read and understand the documents before you simply run commands from the internet.

Comment: AFAIK, using ufw under CentOS causes issues...

Comment: Ufw is a frontend to iptables so there should be no issue but I am more familiar with Debian and arch then CentOS

Comment: Do you happen to know how to achieve the same using firewalld?